# what is the difference between collapse and visible?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Visibility.Collapsed and Visibility.Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886742/difference-between-visibility-collapsed-and-visibility-hidden)

i am working on localization .and i can not get meaning of the visibility and collapse.

```
 public Visibility CompanyModificationAllowed
    {
        get
        {
            if ((User.Priviledges & PriviledgeConstants.USER) != 0)
                return Visibility.Visible;

            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Explain in brief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Visible: the element is visible.
- Collapsed: the element is not, and the layout doesn't even have space for it.
- Hidden: the element is not visible, but the layout reserves spaces for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx

Comment: what is the mean of **"the element is not, and the layout doesn't even have space for it."**

Comment: @prjndhi: I believe it means that the element is completely not rendered.  Whereas with `Hidden` the element itself isn't rendered, but the space which it would occupy is.