# Unable to reorder items in GridView when WrapPanel is used UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, wrappanel, winrt-xaml-toolkit

And am creating a sorting app and in some cases i will hide the gridview item and i encountered the same error as this person:

[Hide GridViewItem and reposition items in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422092/hide-gridviewitem-and-reposition-items-in-gridview)

So I implemented the fix and it worked, but it suddenly disallowed be to drag and reorder items in my GridView.And from what I can tell it only appeared after I implemented the WrapPanel into my `gridView.ItemsPanel` and by removing it I am immediately able to reorder again.

and here's my XML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="ImageSorting.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ImageSorting"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data ="using:ImageSorting.Models"
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="SelectFolder" Content="Select Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,11,10,0" Background="#80a4ec" Click="SelectFolder_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddFolder" Content="Add Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,11,125,0" Background="#84eeb1" Click="AddFolder_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="Save" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,11,230,0" Background="#ece880" Click="Save_Click"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ImageFolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin=" 20 11 0 0" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ImageFolder_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem>All Images</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="ImageGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,60,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImgList, Mode=OneWay}"  CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Images">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="Image" Width="206" Height="158" Source="{x:Bind imageData}" DoubleTapped="Image_DoubleTapped"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="15" Text="{x:Bind imageNumber}" Margin="10 5 0 0"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" Width="100" FontSize="15" Text="{x:Bind altChar}" Margin="10 5 0 0"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="altNumber"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="0" Margin="35 0 0 0" Click="altNumber_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="True">
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
    <Grid x:Name="ConfirmGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button x:Name="FolderConfirm" Content="Confirm" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.128,7.104" Click="FolderConfirm_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Image of when i try to drag and reorder GridView's Item with WrapPanel:
[image: Unable to drop to reorder for some reason]

Am I missing something that is stated in the WinRTXamlToolkit, or there no way around this problem.

**UPDATE 2017 Nov 27**

So after some tinkering  as suggested by [@ Xavier Xie - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782612/xavier-xie-msft)  so try implement the drag and drop to reorder feature for winRT toolkit by inheriting the `WrapPanel` class and trying it from there.
Here's what I have found out so far,

1. winRT toolkit `WrapPanel` inherits `Panel` class
2. `WrapPanel` from other libraries like [UWPCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit)
    also inherits Panel hence making me thing that all Dynamic Wrapping needs to inherit the `Panel` class.
3. `Panel` class doesn't have any code for detecting item drag event (either that or I am dragging the wrong thing)
4. `ItemsWrapPanel` is a seal class making it impossible for me to inherit and that goes for any Interface it inherits as well

And this is concluded what I have found out so far and will continue to update this if I found anything.

**Credits goes to [@ Xavier Xie - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782612/xavier-xie-msft)  for pointing me into the right direction for this.**

Answer (score 1):

The WrapPanel of WinRTXamlToolkit has not implemented reordering function. You would need to implement the reordering manually, listening to the drag & drop events.

If you want to implement by yourself, you could read Jerry Nixon's blog [Walkthrough: Reordering items in a GridView with Drag and Drop](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html) to understand the basic principle of GridView's reordering.

As a easy workaround, you could use `ItemsStackPanel` control as its ItemsPanel, it has implemented reordering function. This control also will not have space item there when you hide one item.

Comment: Wow it works, thanks but there's one problem, and i might sound stupid cause i just started coding this myself, After adding `ItemsStackPanel` the gridview item no longer wrap it, maybe it is because `ItemsStackPanel` didn't implement the function that would wrap the item like the default `ItemsWrapGrid`. 
And since I don't really need to the dynamic wrapping of the of the item and it having a static width and height. 
How do I go about doing so ?

Comment: @Annonymous177 You're right. The `ItemsStackPanel` has not implemented the "wrap" function. You could choose to make a custom panel, but for this way, you would need to implement both "reocrding" and "wrap" functions. So, I suggested that you could try to implement the "recording" for WrapPanel of WinRTXamlToolkit as I said in my above reply.

Comment: well I suppose, I should, and just wondering,, how does one go about making a custom panel cause i couldn't find a guide out there that teaches it.

Comment: The [WrapPanel](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs) of WinRTXamlToolkit is a custom panel, you could check its source code to learn how to make a custom panel.

Comment: The official document [XAML custom panels overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/custom-panels-overview) also is for your details.