# Auto-arrange wpf controls in grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I have a wpf (mvvm-light) based form, with Grid and a six buttons, three in a row in two columns. As buttons can be turned on/off in settings, I want to hide some of them, but I don't want to have empty spaces. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Don't use a fixed Grid if you have dynamic content. Use a ListBox or a WrapPanel.

Comment: Are you interested in dynamically adding buttons based on some logic?

Comment: That can be one option.

Answer (score 3):

Use a WrapPanel and set the visibility for a hidden button to `Visibility.Collapsed` (not `Visibility.Hidden` which hides the control but the space for it is still reserved).  You could bind the visibility to a settings value for example.

See here: [Difference between Visibility.Collapsed and Visibility.Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886742/difference-between-visibility-collapsed-and-visibility-hidden)